# Ionic NullInjectorError: No provider for NetworkProvider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi i am trying to determine if my device is connected to the internet or not. But when i run the app 'ionic serve' im getting this error in the console:

NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> NetworkProvider]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> NetworkProvider]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NetworkProvider!

I founf this question [Missing provider for Ionic's Network native plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057489/missing-provider-for-ionics-network-native-plugin) but it doesnt solve my issue can anybody help me?

**network-provider.ts**

```
import { AlertController, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';

export enum ConnectionStatusEnum {
    Online,
    Offline
}


@Injectable()
export class NetworkProvider {

  previousStatus;

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController, 
              public network: Network,
              public eventCtrl: Events) {

    console.log('Hello NetworkProvider Provider');

    this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;

  }

    public initializeNetworkEvents(): void {
        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Online) {
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:offline');
            }
            this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline;
        });
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline) {
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:online');
            }
            this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
        });
    }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    Network,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { NetworkProvider } from '../app/network-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public events: Events,
    public network: Network,
    public networkProvider: NetworkProvider,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      this.networkProvider.initializeNetworkEvents();

                // Offline event
                this.events.subscribe('network:offline', () => {
                    alert('network:offline ==> '+this.network.type);    
                });

                // Online event
                this.events.subscribe('network:online', () => {
                    alert('network:online ==> '+this.network.type);        
          }); 

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to inject `NetworkProvider` when it is not yet declared to be provided in the service itself or the app module. It needs to be declared as a provider just like Network, Statusbar and Splashscreen. Add `NetworkProvider` to the provider array or Change `@Injectable()` to `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})` in `network-provider.ts` to solve this.